# "SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg" Error in Python when using requests.post()

Tags: python, post, arguments

```
response = requests.post("http://api.bf3stats.com/pc/player/", data = player, opt)
```

After running this line in the python IDLE to test things i encounter the syntax error:  non-keyword arg after keyword arg.

Don't know whats going here.

`player` and `opt` are variables that contain a one word string.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try:

`response = requests.post("http://api.bf3stats.com/pc/player/", opt, data=player)`

You cannot put a non-keyword argument after a keyword argument.

Take a look at the docs at http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=keyword%20args#keyword-arguments for more info.

Answer (score 5):

It should be something like this:

```
response = requests.post("http://api.bf3stats.com/pc/player/", data=player, options=opt)
```

Because you can not pass a non-keyword argument (`opt`) after a keyword argument (`data=player`).